# My activity finishes and navigates to the previous activity without the necessary code for that

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity

I have come across a strange problem, I am trying to refresh my current activity so I passed the same activity as both of the intent arguments
`Intent intent = new Intent(Profile_Page_Activity.this, Profile_Page_Activity.class);` and then `finish();` comes afterwards so I wouldn't have two instances of the same activity running at the same time, but what the app does when I run it is, it first of all shows a toast from an entirely different activity which is second in line in previous activities, that neither leads to the current activity nor does the current the current activity leads to it, the toast shown is not from the current activity, then it goes ahead to the immediate previous activity and then finally to that current activity I wanted it to navigate to, exactly like it recognizes the `finish();` code before the intent code but I know something is wrong somewhere because I definitely provided `finish()` after  `Intent intent = new Intent(Profile_Page_Activity.this, Profile_Page_Activity.class);  startActivity(intent);`

This is the method that houses the code point where I'm facing problems

```
private void Updatecredentials2(String textfullname, String textUsername, String textemail, String text_del_phone, String textAddress, String stateAddress, String townAddress) {

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        HashMap<String, Object> userdata = new HashMap<>();
        userdata.put("email", textemail);
        userdata.put("name", textfullname);
        userdata.put("username", textUsername);
        userdata.put("delieveryphone", "+234" + text_del_phone);
        userdata.put("address", textAddress);
        userdata.put("State", stateAddress);
        userdata.put("Town", townAddress);

        databaseReference.child(path).updateChildren(userdata).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Profile_Page_Activity.this, "Credentials updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Profile_Page_Activity.this, Profile_Page_Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Profile_Page_Activity.this, "Credentials update was unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

This method leads to the above method

```
private void validateupdate2() {
        final String textfullname = fullname.getText().toString();
        final String textUsername = username.getText().toString();
        final String textemail = email.getText().toString();
        final String text_del_phone = del_phone.getText().toString();
        final String textAddress = address.getText().toString();
        final String stateAddress = state.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final String townAddress = town_et.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textfullname) || TextUtils.isEmpty(textUsername) || TextUtils.isEmpty(textemail) || TextUtils.isEmpty(text_del_phone) || TextUtils.isEmpty(textAddress)) {
            Toast.makeText(Profile_Page_Activity.this, "Please fill out all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            DatabaseReference cred_check = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usernames");
            cred_check.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot suu : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        if(suu.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())){
                            continue;
                        }
                        if(suu.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(textUsername)){
                            Toast.makeText(Profile_Page_Activity.this, "Username is taken, please provide another one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Updatecredentials2(textfullname, textUsername, textemail, text_del_phone, textAddress, stateAddress, townAddress);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the method from the entirely different activity that houses the toast that shows in my app, the "Already logged in" toast is the one that shows

```
private void Allowaccess(final String useremail, final String userpassword) {
        final DatabaseReference cref;
        cref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        cref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String email = useremail;
                String password = userpassword;

                if (snapshot.hasChild(email.replace(".", " "))) {
                    Users userdata = snapshot.child(email.replace(".", " ")).getValue(Users.class);
                    if (snapshot.child(email.replace(".", " ")).child("password").getValue().toString().equals(password)) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Already Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity2.class));
                        Prevalent.currentOnlineUser = userdata;
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your password might have changed since your last login.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Activity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Activity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue of the `Allowaccess` method - it seems like the listener inside this method is triggered whenever you update something in firebase database. On `Profile_Page_Activity` you perform `databaseReference.child(path).updateChildren(userdata)` which supposedly triggers any listeners registered such as `cref.addValueEventListener` in `Allowaccess` method. So the solution would be to remove `ValueEventListener` after you successfully was logged in, so no other changes are delivered to it.

Regarding refreshing your activity, I think a more suitable approach would be just to call `recreate()` method when you want to refresh your activity.

Comment: Yes thanks, the listener was the problem and I'm aware that the addValueEventListener triggers the onDataChanged method when there is a change at that location so I changed it to addListenerforSingleValueEvent instead, I noticed the snapshot causing the change and the Allowaccess snapshot has access to the same location so I'm wondering how a change in the common location of a snapshot of another activity has an influence on the activity that houses the Allowaccess method which would then trigger the onDatachanged from the Allowaccess

Comment: I thought the activity ended when I called the finish() method and even if any other activity has a snapshot that point to the same location and then causes a change at that location, then it doesn't affect an already finished activity. The recreate method works, the other approach was a crude one lol, Thanks again.

Comment: The reason why `Allowaccess ` is called, is because your `DatabaseReference ` probably keeps track of all registered listeners no matter what activity are they registered in. So if `addListenerforSingleValueEvent ` is triggered only once, it should be fixed.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To refresh your activity you should call `recreate()` method